# Галерея-слайдер на jQuery

Tags: jquery, php, html, javascript, css

Здравствуйте. Прошу помочь с выбором галереи или слайдера на главную страницу. Дело в том, что когда я вставляю галерею при помощи php функций include, то картинки показываются на главной странице (имеется ввиду index.php). Подскажите самую легкую галерею или слайдер, который можно легко подстроить под свои нужды. Заранее сердечено благодарен!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот этот плагин [jShowOff: a jQuery Content Rotator](http://ekallevig.com/jshowoff/).
Достаточно просмотреть было код страницы и посмотреть подключенные js файлы.

Comment: спасибо очень помогли!

Comment: Не за что :)

Answer (score 1):

Советую посмотреть в сторону [iLoad](http://studioad.ru/index/0-8) - для нее и jQuery не нужна.

Comment: Простите, но я, кажется, неправильно выразился. Не галерея, а слайдер. http://www.soccerpro.com/ - как на этом сайте.

Comment: Тогда советую поискать по [плагинам jQuery][1]. Там много чего интересного можно найти. Ну, или почитать про функцию [animate][2] и написать свою галерею.

[1]: http://plugins.jquery.com/search/node/scroller
[2]: http://api.jquery.com/animate

Answer (score 1):

Такой "слайдер", как вы выразились, легко пишется самостоятельно, если есть хоть какие-то познания в js... Манипулирование слоями по таймеру - вот и всё.
Можно попробовать прикрутить [jcarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/), в нём есть возможность запуска карусели и управления ею, единственное что - элементы будут "пролистываться"(увидите в примерах).
Но я, всё же, посоветовал бы написать скрипт самому.

Answer (score 1):

Вот набор, выбирайте понравившийся, все легко ставятся, у всех там есть примеры > [ссылка](http://blueprintds.com/2009/01/20/top-14-jquery-photo-slideshow-gallery-plugins/)

Answer (score 0):

Я когда то использовал - http://nivo.dev7studios.com/
Вроде неплохой.